# Help! My header and footer are going crazy

Tags: header-footer

I'm writing an invoice that's longer than one page. I provided a header and footer that I want to be shown in the same way on every page. Unfortunately, they only show the way I want them on the last page. On every previous page the line spacing in the header and footer is bigger. 
I despair over that problem and didn't find a solution to my problem.
I'll be very grateful for any help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=0cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot,includehead,headheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\def\customerName{Maximilian\ von\ Musterhausen}
\def\addressCompany{Mäxchen\ GmbH}
\def\addressStreet{Musterstr.\ 1}
\def\addressPostcodeCity{10000\ Musterhausen}
\def\addressCountry{Deutschland}
\def\orderNumber{100000}
\def\customerOrderNumber{DE0101010101}
\def\customerNumber{200000}
\def\invoiceNumber{10010010}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\pagemark}{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}
\newcommand{\leadingzero}[1]{\ifnum #1<10 0\the#1\else\the#1\fi}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

% Header & Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\lhead{
\begin{small}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{} R{3.5cm} L{2.5cm}@{}}
        & Datum:                  &  \leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year \\
        &                         &                                                    \\
        & Rechunngs-Nr.:          &  \invoiceNumber                                    \\
        & Ihre Auftragsnummer:    &  \customerOrderNumber                              \\
        & Kundennummer:           &  \customerNumber                                   \\
        & Auftragsnummer:         &  \orderNumber                                      \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{small}
}

\fancyfootoffset[L]{6mm}
\fancyfootoffset[R]{6mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\footskip=30pt

\fancyfoot{
\begin{tiny}
\begin{tabularx}{19.2cm}{@{}L{1.7cm} @{}L{2.7cm} @{}L{1.6cm} X @{}L{1.7cm} @{}L{2.7cm} @{}L{1.6cm} X @{}L{2.5cm} @{}L{2.5cm}@{}}
 Bank 1     &   DE10 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000               && Bank 4     &   DE40 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Geschäftsführer:                    & Geschäftsführer \\
 Bank 2     &   DE20 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC2000             && Bank 5       &   DE50 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Amtsgericht :               & Nummer                                        \\
 Bank 3     &   DE30 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC3000               && Bank 6     &   DE60 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Steuernummer:               & Nummer                  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{tiny}
}

%%%%%%%%%Beginn%des%Dokuments%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L{9cm} X R{5cm}}
\underline{Firma AG • Straße Nummer • PLZ Ort}   && Firma AG                \\
                                                 && Straße Nummer           \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\addressCompany                && PLZ Ort                 \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\customerName                  &&                         \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\addressStreet                 && Telefon: 000/000 00 00  \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\addressPostcodeCity           && Telefax: 000/000 00 0   \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\addressCountry                && E-Mail: e@mail.com      \\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1.1cm}

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}
\Large \textbf{Rechnung} \\
                         \\
Ihre Bestellung:    \\
\end{tabular}


{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{normalsize}
\begin{longtable}{@{}C{1.4cm} | C{1.5cm} | L{8.1cm} | R{2.3cm} | R{2.5cm}@{} }
\textbf{Menge} & \textbf{Art.-Nr.}  & \textbf{Beschreibung}               & \textbf{\centering Einzelpreis \ €}  & \textbf{Gesamtpreis \ €} \\\ \hline
\endhead
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 \hline\hline
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{Versandkosten}                                                                               & 9,99 €                       \\
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{Netto-Summe}                                                                                     & 999,99 €                     \\\ \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{inkl. 19\% MwSt}                                                                                 & 99,99 €                      \\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{normalsize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First things first: Calm down ;-)

Comment: thanks for the edit :) i'm calmed down a bit knowing my problem is now in the hands of pros ;)

Comment: [Crosspost](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,81369.html#81369)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` inside a group. But this command affects the tables in header and footer too if there are page breaks inside this group. On the last page the group is already closed when the header and footer is set.

But you can set the `\arraystretch` for the tables in header and footer to `1` explicitely.

```
\lhead{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}% <- added
\small% <- changed
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{} R{3.5cm} L{2.5cm}@{}}
        & Datum:                  &  \leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year \\
        &                         &                                                    \\
        & Rechunngs-Nr.:          &  \invoiceNumber                                    \\
        & Ihre Auftragsnummer:    &  \customerOrderNumber                              \\
        & Kundennummer:           &  \customerNumber                                   \\
        & Auftragsnummer:         &  \orderNumber                                      \\
\end{tabularx}
}
```

and

```
\fancyfoot{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}% <- added
\tiny% <- changed
\begin{tabularx}{19.2cm}{@{}L{1.7cm} @{}L{2.7cm} @{}L{1.6cm} X @{}L{1.7cm} @{}L{2.7cm} @{}L{1.6cm} X @{}L{2.5cm} @{}L{2.5cm}@{}}
 Bank 1     &   DE10 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000               && Bank 4     &   DE40 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Geschäftsführer:                    & Geschäftsführer \\
 Bank 2     &   DE20 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC2000             && Bank 5       &   DE50 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Amtsgericht :               & Nummer                                        \\
 Bank 3     &   DE30 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC3000               && Bank 6     &   DE60 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Steuernummer:               & Nummer                  \\
\end{tabularx}
}
```

Note that `\small`, `\tiny` etc. are switches and not environments.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=0cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot,includehead,headheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\def\customerName{Maximilian\ von\ Musterhausen}
\def\addressCompany{Mäxchen\ GmbH}
\def\addressStreet{Musterstr.\ 1}
\def\addressPostcodeCity{10000\ Musterhausen}
\def\addressCountry{Deutschland}
\def\orderNumber{100000}
\def\customerOrderNumber{DE0101010101}
\def\customerNumber{200000}
\def\invoiceNumber{10010010}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\pagemark}{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}
\newcommand{\leadingzero}[1]{\ifnum #1<10 0\the#1\else\the#1\fi}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

% Header & Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\lhead{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}%
\small%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{} R{3.5cm} L{2.5cm}@{}}
        & Datum:                  &  \leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year \\
        &                         &                                                    \\
        & Rechunngs-Nr.:          &  \invoiceNumber                                    \\
        & Ihre Auftragsnummer:    &  \customerOrderNumber                              \\
        & Kundennummer:           &  \customerNumber                                   \\
        & Auftragsnummer:         &  \orderNumber                                      \\
\end{tabularx}
}

\fancyfootoffset[L]{6mm}
\fancyfootoffset[R]{6mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\footskip=30pt

\fancyfoot{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}% <- added
\tiny% <- changed
\begin{tabularx}{19.2cm}{@{}L{1.7cm} @{}L{2.7cm} @{}L{1.6cm} X @{}L{1.7cm} @{}L{2.7cm} @{}L{1.6cm} X @{}L{2.5cm} @{}L{2.5cm}@{}}
 Bank 1     &   DE10 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000               && Bank 4     &   DE40 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Geschäftsführer:                    & Geschäftsführer \\
 Bank 2     &   DE20 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC2000             && Bank 5       &   DE50 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Amtsgericht :               & Nummer                                        \\
 Bank 3     &   DE30 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC3000               && Bank 6     &   DE60 0000 0000 0000 0000 00 &   BANKBIC1000                && Steuernummer:               & Nummer                  \\
\end{tabularx}
}

%%%%%%%%%Beginn%des%Dokuments%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L{9cm} X R{5cm}}
\underline{Firma AG • Straße Nummer • PLZ Ort}   && Firma AG                \\
                                                 && Straße Nummer           \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\addressCompany                && PLZ Ort                 \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\customerName                  &&                         \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\addressStreet                 && Telefon: 000/000 00 00  \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\addressPostcodeCity           && Telefax: 000/000 00 0   \\
\hspace{7mm}\large\addressCountry                && E-Mail: e@mail.com      \\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1.1cm}

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}
\Large \textbf{Rechnung} \\
                         \\
Ihre Bestellung:    \\
\end{tabular}


{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\normalsize
\begin{longtable}{@{}C{1.4cm} | C{1.5cm} | L{8.1cm} | R{2.3cm} | R{2.5cm}@{} }
\textbf{Menge} & \textbf{Art.-Nr.}  & \textbf{Beschreibung}               & \centering\textbf{ Einzelpreis \ €}  & \textbf{Gesamtpreis \ €} \\\hline
\endhead
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 10                    & 11111              & Artikel                        & 9,99                                  & 99,90                        \\
 \hline\hline
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{Versandkosten}                                                                               & 9,99 €                       \\
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{Netto-Summe}                                                                                     & 999,99 €                     \\\hline
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{inkl. 19\% MwSt}                                                                                 & 99,99 €                      \\\hline
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```